# how to give filling that window is minimize in java swing on clicking close button

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I am trying to minimize the JFrame on the click of the close button for that i have write the following code.

```
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.ICONIFIED);
        }
    });
```

my code is running successfully and getting proper output but the problem is that the window is getting minimized but user can not feel that window is minimized. I am not able to give that effect on view part that window is getting minimized

Comment: *"I am trying to minimize the JFrame on the click of the close button"*  Why build such a counter-intuitive UI?  If an app. on my screen refused to exit on clicking the `x` button, I'd go straight to task manager and kill the process, then uninstall it (then bad mouth the programmer from one end of the Earth to the other).

Comment: @Andrew Thompson this is debatable and a matter of opinion. For instance, there are many applications that offer the possibility to minimize to the system tray upon clicking the close button, such as the Windows task manager itself